# Document is undefined , can't open directly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This gives me 'document' is undefined error with no reason ! I can't open the file directly.

This is the code :

```
var main = function() {
  $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 200);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "285px"
    }, 200);
  });

  $('.icon-close').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "-285px"
    }, 200);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 200);
  });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

This is the html :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='css/custom.css' rel='stylesheet'>

  </head>
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <body>

    <div class="menu">

      <div class="icon-close">
      </div>

      <ul>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Main body -->
    <div class="jumbotron">

      <div class="icon-menu">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        Menu
      </div>

     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So what's the problem ? I put my js.js in the root and the rest of them are in folders.

Comment: Where are you calling the jQuery script? It is missing, and therefore you have the error :)

Comment: you must load your jquery library before writing jquery script, please add it above your script and error will go.

Comment: i ve played with it , and during i accidently deleted the one line code !!
idiot...
tnx for ur help

Answer (score 0):

you have to include jquery before you can use it:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```